# How to set vertex color to selected faces in python?

Tags: python, vertex-colors

I want to set vertex color to selected faces.

```
import bpy

mesh = context.active_object.data
vertex_color = mesh.vertex_colors.get('VertexColor')
if not vertex_color:
   vertex_color = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='VertexColor', do_init=True)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')
mesh.use_paint_mask = True
bpy.data.brushes["Draw"].color = (0, 1, 1)
bpy.ops.paint.vertex_color_set('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Your script seems to work as-is.  What problem are you having?

Comment: `context = bpy.context` is missing after line 1. But then it works like a charm.